# Ceph-deploy is not creating ceph.bootstrap-rbd.keyring file

Tags: ceph

I am learning Ceph storage (luminous) with one admin node and two nodes for OSD and MON etc. as I following the doc http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/start/quick-ceph-deploy/ to setup my initial storage cluster and stuck after executing this below command. as per the document the below command should out put 6 files but this file "ceph.bootstrap-rbd.keyrin" is missing in the admin node directory where I execute ceph-deploy commands.

ceph-deploy --username sanadmin mon create-initial

I am not sure whether it is a normal behaviour are I am really missing something. appreciate you help on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not important. Because rbd is native service for ceph. Do not worry  about that

Comment: Thanks, I have skipped this file and started using the storage. thanks for taking time to answer.